Webform mail formatting broken after moving to symfony-mailer-lite from swiftmailer
In march 2024 we left swiftmailer and switched to symfony-mailer-lite.
Everything looked well until we found that the font for mails which had no template specified in our theme had a default font like times new roman instead of arial.
We then took the mail template from the old swiftmailer and put it in our theme thought this will fix it.
It did fix it for the font but not for the formatting. Before any Element title was bold and styled in the mails now only plain text.
So now I wonder if there is something else we missed.
Here are two mails, the first is from february and contains all the style info. The second is from now.
    <html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style type="text/css">
table tr td {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <table width="800px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
          <p>Gesendet am: Fr., 26.04.2024 - 19:35</p>
<p>Gesendet von: admin</p>
<p>Gesendete Eingaben:</p>
  <b>Anrede</b><br>Familie<br><br><b>Vorname</b><br>Dixisset<br><br><b>Nachname</b><br>Loremipsum<br><br><b>Straße</b><br>Dixisset<br><br><b>Hausnummer</b><br>Oratione<br><br><b>PLZ</b><br>Loremipsum<br><br><b>Ort</b><br>Loremipsum<br><br><b>E-Mail</b><br><a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a><br><br><b>Telefonnummer</b><br>Oratione<br><br><b>Betreff</b><br>Loremipsum<br><br><b>Ihr Anliegen</b><br>Quae cum dixisset, finem ille. Quamquam non negatis nos intellegere quid sit voluptas, sed quid ille dicat. Progredientibus autem aetatibus sensim tardeve potius quasi nosmet ipsos cognoscimus. Gloriosa ostentatio in constituendo summo bono. Qui-vere falsone, quaerere mittimus-dicitur oculis se privasse; Duarum enim vitarum nobis erunt instituta capienda. Comprehensum, quod cognitum non habet? Qui enim existimabit posse se miserum esse beatus non erit. Causa autem fuit huc veniendi ut quosdam hinc libros promerem. Nunc omni virtuti vitium contrario nomine opponitur.<br><br><b>Weitergabe von personenbezogenen Daten</b><br>Ich bin nicht damit einverstanden, dass meine in diesem Formular erhobenen personenbezogenen Daten zum Zweck der Beantwortung meiner Anfrage an andere Behörden der Landesverwaltung, Bundes- oder kommunale Behörden weitergeleitet werden. Wir weisen vorsorglich darauf hin, dass Ihre Anfrage u. U. nicht beantwortet werden kann, wenn Sie hiermit nicht einverstanden sind.<br><br>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

The current one:
<!-- THEME DEBUG --><!-- THEME HOOK: 'symfony_mailer_lite_email' --><!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * symfony-mailer-lite-email--webform--kontakt-e-mail.html.twig
   * symfony-mailer-lite-email--webform.html.twig
   x symfony-mailer-lite-email.html.twig
--><!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/hw_radix_standard/templates/mail/symfony-mailer-lite-email.html.twig' --><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style type="text/css">
table tr td {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div flags="63">
  <table width="800px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
          <b>symfony-mailer-lite-email</b>
          <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'webform_email_message_html' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * webform-email-message-html--kontakt--email--e-mail.html.twig
   * webform-email-message-html--kontakt--email.html.twig
   * webform-email-message-html--kontakt.html.twig
   x webform-email-message-html.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/webform/templates/webform-email-message-html.html.twig' -->
<b>webform-email-message-html</b>
<p>Gesendet am: Fr., 26.04.2024 - 13:44</p>
<p>Gesendet von: admin</p>
<p>Gesendete Eingaben:</p>
<p>  Anrede<br>Frau</p>
<p>  Vorname<br>Dixisset</p>
<p>  Nachname<br>Dixisset</p>
<p>  Straße<br>Oratione</p>
<p>  Hausnummer<br>Oratione</p>
<p>  PLZ<br>Oratione</p>
<p>  Ort<br>Loremipsum</p>
<p>  E-Mail<br><a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a></p>
<p>  Telefonnummer<br>Oratione</p>
<p>  Betreff<br>Loremipsum</p>
<p>  Ihr Anliegen<br>Quae cum dixisset, finem ille. Quamquam non negatis nos intellegere quid sit voluptas, sed quid ille dicat. Progredientibus autem aetatibus sensim tardeve potius quasi nosmet ipsos cognoscimus. Gloriosa ostentatio in constituendo summo bono. Qui-vere falsone, quaerere mittimus-dicitur oculis se privasse; Duarum enim vitarum nobis erunt instituta capienda. Comprehensum, quod cognitum non habet? Qui enim existimabit posse se miserum esse beatus non erit. Causa autem fuit huc veniendi ut quosdam hinc libros promerem. Nunc omni virtuti vitium contrario nomine opponitur.</p>
<p>  Weitergabe von personenbezogenen Daten<br>Ich bin damit einverstanden, dass meine in diesem Formular erhobenen personenbezogenen Daten zum Zweck der Beantwortung meiner Anfrage an andere Behörden der Landesverwaltung, Bundes- oder kommunale Behörden weitergeleitet werden. </p>


<!-- END OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/webform/templates/webform-email-message-html.html.twig' -->

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/hw_radix_standard/templates/mail/symfony-mailer-lite-email.html.twig' -->

We did not have any special template with all the styles for the mail body.
So I wonder where this information did come from before.
Any changes in webform module, core or is symfony-mailer just dropping it?
Found this issue in symfony-mailer-lite https://git.drupalcode.org/project/symfony_mailer_lite/-/commit/623c53acc21bd1d82fad41bec7cfd8eacd1e7546 and changed the config to not use the default content in the message settings of symfony-mailer-lite - but no change to the behaviour. Somehow the HTML of message.body from webform gehts stripped.

The templates from the Webforms module still use <b></b> in many places. Like here:
{% if options.email %}
  {% if title %}<b>{{ title }}</b><br />{% endif %}{{ value }}<br /><br />

Applying a textformat with HTML Filter with CKEditor throws those tags out cause it does no longer allow deprecated HTML Tags. If you allow [B] in CKEditor it allows only <strong></strong> but not <b></b>. The filtered tags can not be manually overriden in the UI.
So either override the webform templates html in your theme, turn filtering of in your textformat or write a custom module or patch like here https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton/issues/2910028 to allow other tags or styles.

You need to implement one of the following files in your themes templates folder:

symfony-mailer-lite-email--webform--kontakt-e-mail.html.twig
symfony-mailer-lite-email--webform.html.twig
symfony-mailer-lite-email.html.twig

This will override the file modules/contrib/webform/templates/webform-email-message-html.html.twig, which is currently where the HTML is coming from. You can customize it with the HTML that meets your requirements.

Tried that already, but there must have been something else broken, the formatting broke when merging our feature branch, where I removed swiftmailer, was merged into dev branch. So either some config got lost or some co-dev played arround with message.body in webform.module. Did a dpm($message[body]) and the bold tags are missing there already. Modules are same in each FB, Core Version differs.

The code you posted shows that the template you tried is not being used, and the default template is being used. The way I have told you to do it, is how it is done.

It seems that the setting /admin/webform/config/elements for E-Mail-Text format breaks the HTML of the token [webform_submission:values]. As soon as this is changed from default, to e.g. minimal, the formatting is missing in the mail.
Setting it to default results in plain html in the Mail-Template editor. Used to work fine before but seems to got broken this march with some core, cke, module updates.
